# PHP question on encoding (latin1_swedish_ci vs utf8_unicode_ci)

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I have a question regarding encodings. In my MySQL database I have encoded users in latin1_swedish_ci (bad idea). Now I connect my iPhone application to Facebook and retrieve the list of friend names, and I would like to see if I already have these friends in my application. Sadly when I try to do the query I get this error:

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

So basically I try to mix the Facebook friend's name (in utf8) with the names in my dabatase (latin1).

I don't want to migrate the whole database to utf8, I just would like to know if it's possible in PHP to check if the name encoding is compatible with latin1, or at least if it's possible to encode all the names in latin1 and do the query, and if not just skip the name.

Does anyone of you know if it's possible to do something like this?
Thanks,

Masiar

Comment: Please show the query that leads to this error

Comment: Actually I cannot, it's a query formed by a PHP script that takes each name in the request and put it in this form: `[...] OR name LIKE ".$name." ` and so on...

Comment: why not echo it in the PHP script? And we need to know the exact encodings of the columns. Are you mixing column encodings in your query?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM 'sl_user' WHERE nome LIKE 'name1' OR nome LIKE 'name2' OR nome LIKE 'name3' OR nome LIKE 'name4' OR nome LIKE 'name5' OR nome LIKE 'name5' OR nome LIKE 'name6' OR nome LIKE 'name7' OR ...` that's it, a list full of names. The columns are all encoded in `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully sure how are you looking for your friends in your application - via a search box or something? What is the role of the PHP script?

But I think you can solve the issue by specifying character set and collation at the time of connecting to your database. By the way, I assume you are using MySQL.

Run the following 3 queries each time you establish a DB connection, though I think the first 2 might suffice for you.

```
SET character_set_connection = utf8
SET character_set_client = utf8
SET character_set_results = utf8
```

Comment: The role of the PHP script is to take the POST request from the iPhone containing all the friend's name and check if there are some in the database of my application. I still have to test your approach, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok thanks!

I think in your case, you'll need to set character_set_connection to latin1.